# Byte array length not correct

Tags: java, arrays

In the code I generate an array of bytes from 2 integers using byte buffer. When I try to write the array to an output stream I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. The length parameter for the write(array, offset, length) method in OutputSteam believes the array to be smaller than the arrays length even when I pass the property from the array itself. I checked that the file is big enough by writing dummy data yet I still get the same exception.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("File");
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.alocate(Integer.BYTES*2);
buff.putInt(18);
buff.putInt(32);
byte[] array = buff.array();

out.write(array, 0, array.length); // Heres where the problem comes in
```

Comment: what is your offset?

Comment: That code is not valid Java.  If you want help you need to post the _actual_ Java code that fails, not your paraphrasing of it.  Also post the stack trace and indicate the values of variables such as `offset`.

Comment: Nope, the problem comes in earlier than the line with the comment. For now, it is the fact that you are posting code that wont even compile.

Comment: Copy-paste the code verbatim from your editor. Every single letter counts here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an arrray has N objects, and the last object is indexed by N-1, since it starts at 0. Array.Length is N, and you want N-1.

Comment: That `write` call is perfectly valid: `element b[off] is the first byte written and b[off+len-1] is the last byte written by this operation`

Comment: I have tried to that, no joy, even after subtracting more than half

Comment: In that case, I have no idea. I think it could be a problem with `out` itself. The best way to solve problems, in my experience, is to either listen to errors or post more details online.

Answer (score 0):

Because `array.length` gives you number of bytes, you want to use [`Integer.BYTES`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#BYTES) (bytes per integer) not [`Integer.SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#SIZE) (bits per integer) when allocating for the buffer.

```
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.BYTES*2);
buff.putInt(18);
buff.putInt(32);
byte[] array = buff.array();
```

Comment: This still results in an IndexOutOfBounds Exception on writing to the output stream